# How can i set hideEffect attribute to the GridRow using actionscript in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

i want to set fade effect to the GridRow when i remove it using removeChld() function

please tell me the solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Grid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.display.DisplayObject;

            import mx.containers.GridRow;
            import mx.effects.Effect;
            import mx.effects.Fade;
            import mx.events.EffectEvent;

            override public function removeChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
                if(child is GridRow) {
                    var fade:Fade = new Fade;
                    fade.alphaFrom = 1;
                    fade.alphaTo = 0;
                    fade.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_END, fadeEndHandler);
                    fade.play([child]);
                } else {
                    super.removeChild(child);
                }

                return child;
            }

            private function fadeEndHandler(e:EffectEvent):void {
                super.removeChild(GridRow(e.effectInstance.target));
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Grid>
```

Make this a new MXML component, like FadingGrid, and use as normal. However, now removeChildAt is not overridden and thus using it won't produce the fade effect.

Comment: This looks good, though I haven't tried it. Tushar, I am assuming you have a button to fire the removeChild() function. I would implement this by using that button to call the fade effect like shown and on the event listener EffectEvent.EFFECT_END call the removeChild() function, then you don't have to override anything.

Comment: Yes, you could have a button to call removeChild(). Of course, you have to know which row you are deleting so that you can pass the row itself as a parameter. This piece of code does not work with removeChildAt() since it is not overridden.

You could implement this effect the way you described, but wrapping the behavior into a new class makes it possible to reuse it elsewhere. All it really takes is creating one .mxml file and putting the code into it - the overrides may be intimidating, but they are in fact quite useful if you want to do custom things.